# How can I view our currently active AWS services that we're actually using?

Tags: amazon-web-services

The AWS console just lists every single service that AWS offers.  Is there an easy way to make it just show the services that we're actually currently using?  I don't know why does everything with AWS seem to be far more difficult than it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to show only the services that you are currently using. If AWS doesn't show all the services, how does AWS expect you to know about the new services. just joking.

Honestly, I started exploring the new services only after seeing them on AWS dashboard. If you consider that as an inconvenience, there is nothing you can do about it. But if you are curious to know about the services you are using, then the billing dashboard will list all the services you are using and the charges for it.  For example, to see the services used in [June 2017](https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home?region=us-west-1#/bill?year=2017&month=6)

Note: You need certain IAM privileges to access the [Billing Dashboard](https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home?region=us-west-1#/)

Comment: Yeah, I would rather not have to ask to be granted access to Billing since that's outside of the scope of my responsibilities in the company.  It just seems wrong that that's the only way to see a simple list of the services we're using (that should be the purpose of the AWS console!), but I guess it is what it is.